# Answers with broken links to software that is no longer available

Tags: discussion, answers, answer-quality, flagging, hyperlinks

Six years ago I asked a question for recommendations for Firefox extensions:  [Firefox extension to copy the title and URL of the page to the clipboard](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3772/firefox-extension-to-copy-the-title-and-url-of-the-page-to-the-clipboard).  Since then, Firefox completely changed the way that extensions work.  Most answers recommend extensions that are:

1. No longer available (the pages on the Firefox site for them are 404 Not Found.)
2. Don't work with Firefox anymore even if you found an alternate source to download.

I recently received an [up-to-date answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/75122/92) to the question that brought this to my attention and I updated [my own answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/3774/92).   However all the other answers are completely out of date and no longer useful. Anybody that finds this question has to scroll past pages of highly-voted out-of-date answers to get to something that works.

How should this situation be handled?  I can imagine several possible solutions:

1. Comment on each out-of-date answer and hope the author comes back to update it.
2. Edit each out-of-date answer to remove the broken link and put a notice at the top of the answer that it is no longer any good.
3. Flag each out-of-date answer so that a moderator can remove it

Comment: This is a superb question. Personally, I need to spend more time thinking about it before arriving at an opinion. Another aspect of this issue is what to do when the *Accepted Answer* is no longer valid. I am looking forward to reading posts from our community regarding these issues.

Comment: Looks like our community has no opinion on this: more than 2 years later there's not a single answer. It might be nice if answers could have a kind of banner pointing out "this is no longer available", which a mod could toggle. Maybe making use of the "post notice"? Unfortunately, there are no "free-form" notices. I never checked, maybe we can add our own?

Comment: [This answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3772/firefox-extension-to-copy-the-title-and-url-of-the-page-to-the-clipboard/75122#75122) begins with "*All of the above recommendations are dead...*". This was likely a useful addition at the time it was added, but now the only correct answer appears *above* this one.  The helpful information has suffered the same fate it was intended to correct. ¶ (SE really needs something that will prevent "above" and "below" from being used in answers; they are more likely to become wrong than the links are.)

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the reasons that we discourage product recommendations on super user.

In many cases the author is *gone* so pinging the author might not be a good solution on its own.

To me

- If its a completely obsolete technology that someone is unlikely to effectively use, and relies on a dead link to work, closure of the *question*  is the right answer.
- If a resource has moved, replacing it with the new link is a good idea. Sometimes forks are of ambiguous officialness, and we had someone try to replace all the links to a fairly major project to their own fork of it on SU, so some form of documentation/discussion first, via comments or better yet meta might be nice.
- If its possible to 'replace' the link with an archive link and still have the answer usable, this would be a decent alternative.
- if the accepted answer is 'dead' - a comment or notice in the answer itself might be useful. Sometimes dead sites get converted to spam portals, in which case deletion would be the best option.
- if the best course of action is unclear - a meta post discussing the question and its answers would be a decent form of governance/documentation of what was done/decided. Sometimes a member of the community might have an idea on the first three options. If the first option, of closing the question is incorrect discussion would be fruitful too.

Comment: There's also the case where the link (and the software it points to) is dead – but the answer helds sufficient details to give a better clue what to look for. In that case it might be a good idea to "prepend" a warning note telling the reader the software is no longer available / the link is dead, but leaving the answer otherwise as-is. (made a comment so you can integrate that with your answer if you wish – looks like a "canonical" one already, covering many cases ;)